# What are all of the quotes in the OP of Eden of the East from?

Tags: theme-song, eden-of-the-east

In the Eden of the East opening, there are a lot of quotes from different sources. The only one I know the origin of is "The abuse of greatness is when it disjoins remorse from power," which is from *Julius Caesar* by William Shakespeare. I don't know what the other quotes that show up on the screen are from or are in reference to. Can someone tell me?

Comment: Could you list the quotes here for convenience of anyone answering the question? ;)

Answer (score 7):

This [blogpost](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2009/07/anime-eden-of-east.html) has a transcript of all of the text from the opening. Not all of them are famous quotes.

> "*I saw you in Heaven
>   and heard of your glory
>   You saved our world from the fallen angels
>   I saw Messiah standing
>   Standing before me with no words
>   Nothing but "Hope"
>   When we lost dread, a Demon was laughing 
>   But now you are showing us wonder
>   Giving your love
>   With awe, down on my knees again
>   I've got to know you're the one
>   The only one reveals the world*"

This is repeated multiple times throughout the OP and seems to be part of the song [東のエデン挿入歌「Reveal The World」](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO28pvdkyJI)

> "*The abuse of greatness is when it disjoins remorse from power.*"

As you've noted, it's [Brutus from Julius Caesar, by William Shakespeare](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/17932/).

> "*Mail
>
>   Own date
>
>   Media tool
>
>   Appli
>
>   Camera
>
>   Phone book
>
>   Iseg
>
>   Music
>
>   Service
>
>   Setting
>
>   You've got mail
>
>   Calling
>
>   Talking*"

These seem to be options (partially obscured) of the phone.

> "*Let me walk with you when I'm lost in the wild
>   I know you always lead me to another Eden
>   Let me bless your name, O Lord, O Lord
>   Your words will never fade away
>   Since we believe you're the light on earth
>   Reveals the world*"

Also from the "Reveal the world" song lyrics.

The rest seems to be proper names and instances from the show itself, like "*noblesse oblige*", and "*Juiz*", and "*Selecao system
12 persons selected in Japan*". So the only real quote I guess is from the Julius Caesar play.

Comment: "Noblesse oblige" is an old French expression, meaning that being a noble comes with responsibilities. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_oblige).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this case noblesse oblige means, "I nobly oblige myself". Otherwise it means the obligations of nobility.